# Is there a way to use index properly in this v-for to not get an error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using index in a v-for to try to use it in a function to delete that item from the array. Index is defined but never used is popping as the error from the linter.

I am unsure of the right way to place the index, as this is the way it is instructed in the tutorial.

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <app-quote v-for="(quote,index) in quotes" :key="quote.id" @click.native="deleteQuote">{{ quote }}</app-quote>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Quote from './Quote.vue';

export default {
    props: ['quotes'],
    components: {
        appQuote: Quote
    },
    methods: {
        deleteQuote(index) {
            this.$emit('quoteDeleted', index);
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: `@click.native="deleteQuote(index)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the index to `deleteQuote` explicitly:

```
<app-quote v-for="(quote, index) in quotes" :key="quote.id" @click.native="deleteQuote(index)">{{ quote }}</app-quote>
```

In general, you can disable the linter for a line:

```
<!-- eslint-disable-next-line -->
```

But in this case, it is not necessary.

Comment: Disabling the linter for something like this wouldn't be a good idea

Comment: @Phil you are right, it would be a bad idea. I edited and leaving it as a reference

Comment: I was able to pass index explicity to ```deleteQuote```.